# Loop condition and Performance

Tags: performance, loops

Is there any difference in performance between following two code segments? Or do compilers handle the difference? The first one calls count() method at each iteration. The second one only calls it once.

```
//first code segment
for(i=0; i<count(array); i++){
    //code
}

//second code segment
length = count(array);
for(i=0; i<length; i++){
    //code
}
```

Comment: It depends on the language. If the array can resize dynamically(as in javascript for example) then the compiler cannot optimize it because the count value can change inside the loop. In languages like C where the arrays are static i suppose the compiler can, and do actually cache the result.

Answer (score 2):

In theory second code segment should be faster. But when I measured two following code segments in C# it shows that the first segment works faster:

```
// First code segment.

var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

int[] array = new int[1000000];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result is **63566** ms.

```
// Second code segments

var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

int[] array = new int[1000000];
int arrayLength = array.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result is **66564** ms.

Comment: In your test, the vast majority of time will be spent on printing each number. Hence the test says nothing about the actual loop construct.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C and *array* isn't changing in the loop then the second code segment is often better (and is in no case worse) than the first from a performance standpoint.

Calling a function once versus multiple times is better (all other thing being equal).

The compiler sometimes can move code from inside the loop to above the loop.  This is called [loop invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion).  But hoisting a function call is non-trivial.